# Cannot find API Key page

Tags: ionic-framework, prestashop, ionic-appflow

I purchased an app which uses Ionic, and for their Push plugin it requires Ionic Api Token.
The domain from the video changed, but it redirects to a kinda same tree /app/code/ but config/keys is not present, also I couldn't be able to find the url to get My api keys, since the Prestashop plugin to push notifications requires the api token, where can I find it?
https://youtu.be/HKCWNZ2mbPs?t=516
This is the moment in the setup where they acquire the api token.

Comment: Can you share relevant code and exact plugins your app is using

Comment: It would be helpful to know which PrestaShop module you are using (free/paid?) and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: It's a custom paid plugin IcyMobi Prestashop, in which it requires the api token

Comment: @BrunoLeveque I'm not getting any error, I'm unable to complete the config of the PrestaShop module because it requires an API Token from Ionic framework which I can't find. also if You would open the Youtube link I linked, You would see in less than 10 seconds the Api Token Page, and the PrestaShop module..